# NPAPI self rendering plugin under safari (32 bit versus 64 bit)

Tags: cocoa, plugins, safari, npapi

I am working in safari, on top of OSX, using core graphics and I've got a plugin running two threads (main and rendering timer thread). The rendering timer thread invokes "NPN_InvalidateRect" while the main plugin thread handles the corresponding event and redraws itself. However this seems to work differently in safari  32 bit versus safari 64 bit:

- 64 bit (cocoa event model): requires NPN_InvalidateRect + NPN_ForceRedraw  = correct redrawing
- 32 bit (cocoa if supported, otherwise carbon): NPN_InvalidateRect = correct redrawing
  however, doing both NPN_InvalidateRect + NPN_ForceRedraw (like 64 bit case) causes flickering image.

Questions:

1. Is there a better way to force a plugin to render itself, while sticking to native NPAPI, core graphics and support for carbon&cocoa event models.
2. If not, how can i detect, at runtime, if the browser is running as 32 versus 64 bit application so i can pick which NPN functions of call.

Thanks,

(cross-posted to firebreath, I will post responses in both places)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this:

> The rendering timer thread invokes "NPN_InvalidateRect"

Is a serious problem, unless you really mean that your rendering timer thread causes NPN_InvalidateRect to be called on the main plugin thread. NPAPI is explicitly not threadsafe, and you are required to call methods like NPN_InvalidateRect on the main thread.

Second, you should really just not call NPN_ForceRedraw. Chromium, Firefox OOP, WebKit2, and almost certainly Safari's OOP mode (which is what you are getting in 64-bit) treat NPN_ForceRedraw as a no-op; the concept of forcing an immediate redraw goes against the whole model of OOP plugins. In all cases you should just call NPN_InvalidateRect, and trust the browser to call you back. In the OOP-plugin world, you should not expect to be able to *force* the browser to render a plugin at any given moment.

Comment: In addition, why exactly are you "rendering" from another thread? you know that you can only draw in response to a draw event of some sort, right? And in that case, it will always be on the main thread. One option would be to set up a timer to just call NPN_InvalidateRect at a certain frequency on the main thread; that approach is supported by FireBreath (you weren't explicit about whether or not you're using it) with the AutoInvalidate functions on the PluginWindowMac classes.